# Chrome & IE can't access local website, while Firefox can. How to debug?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, virtualbox, dns, internet-explorer

### 1. Enviroment

#### 1.1 Host machine

- Windows 8.1 Enterprise
- Chrome v42.0.2311.152
- Firefox v38.0.1
- IE v11.0.9600.17031
- VirtialBox
- Vagrant
- 80 port forwarded to port 80 at guest machine at 192.168.56.101
- hosts entry for www.myproject.wip pointing to 192.168.56.101
- no proxy in IE/Chrome network settings
- automatically discover DNS
- DNS prefetching disabled
- third party search engines in address bar disabled

#### 1.2 Guest machine

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Apache 2.4

### 2. The problem

With virtual machine running when I open Firefox and browse www.myproject.wip it correctly displays the local website hosted on Apache inside the virtual machine.

When I try the same in IE or Chrome as a result I get "could determine the IP address for host www.myproject.wip". This is a standard error page from my organization's DNS.

## How to debug this?

I've tried:

- disableing all plugins
- clearing browser cache
- `ipconfig /flushdns`
- `chrome://net-internals/#dns` clear host cache

to no avail :(

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your hosts file of Windows:

```
192.168.56.101 www.myproject.wip
```

This file is located at this path:

```
c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

Hope this help

Comment: I already did. See point 1.1 of my post. `hosts entry for www.myproject.wip pointing to 192.168.56.101`

Answer (score 0):

Old post but,
Possibly change hosts on the device too to point to your host machine.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260141/adding-vm-etc-host-entries-that-point-to-host-machine-with-vagrant-and-puphpet

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to describe the procedure. (Leave the link for reference.)